# Module is deactivating itself

Tags: 7

For some reason, when testing my module (displays a form), the module seems to "disable" itself. I reload the page, and the block isn't displayed anymore.
If I go in the "Module" menu, my module is there, but unchecked.

I unfortunately do not have a pattern to reproduce what makes this happen. The website is local online for testing purpose, so no-one can tamper with it.

What could be causing this problem, and how can I find the cause?

EDIT : Here's the module.info :

```
name = "Module title"
description = "Module description"
package = Companyname
core = 7.x
version = 0.0.1
configure = admin/config/system/mymodule
```

Comment: You must provide more informations. As far as we know, you could have a drupal_uninstall_module('your_module') in your form code.

Comment: Like I said, i don't really have a pattern that reproduce that behavior. What kind of information do you need? Obviously, if I had put a "drupal_uninstall_module()" i would see where the problem is :)

Comment: I once had a problem like this, and it depended from two modules in conflict. You should circunscribe your problem. Try to disable beta/alpha/dev modules and see if the problem persists. You need to know if the problem is your module or something else.

Comment: Did you implement `hook_requirements()`, in your module? Does your module depends from other modules?

Comment: Please post your module.info file

Comment: @DavidThomas : added like you asked :)

Comment: You most likely have a conflicting module somewhere, or you have enabled it, and maybe changed the name of it or something that would cause it to conflict and Drupal would therefore turn it off.

Comment: @Ebpo, although not the verbatim version ( e.g can check for project name conflict etc.. ) the .info file looks ok, other than the slightly odd version number. Try with version = 1.0 otherwise if not that will need to see the module code. Possibly a naming conflict with another module

Comment: As @notme first stated, it was a conflict between custom modules. Thanks for the help!